# Module not found using npm start for the APP.JS

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

this is a similar question -- so apologies, but I was unable to resolve my issue by following the advice, to reformulate the import with a `./` or `../`
My code for App.js is below:

```
import './App.css';
import Movies from './Component/Movies/Movies';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/*Movie component*/}
      <Movies/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting the error:

````
Failed to compile.                                                           
                                                                             
./src/App.js                                                                 
Module not found: Can't resolve ./Component/Movies/Movies' in C:\Users\John\Documents\550Backups\movies\omdb_movies\src'      ```
````

But I know my file Movies.js is in the path:

````
C:\Users\John\Documents\550Backups\movies\omdb_movies\src\Components\Movies\Movies.js```
````

Any guidance greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the 's' on import. Try this:

```
import Movies from './Components/Movies/Movies';
```